# Guessing Indentation of text file with python

Tags: python, readfile

I am working with a program that generates a specific file format, that I have to read and modify with python scripts. This file is is supposed to be tab delimited, but I haven't been able to recognize the tab character. Any good way to read this kind of file, and generate a new one in the same formatting?

```
1. Base Year Data for Calibration
   1.1 Observed Data per Internal Zone
      Sector     Zone   ExogProd InducedPro ExogDemand      Price ValueAdded  Attractor 
           1        1       5000          0          0 14409.8204          0          1 
           1        2        800          0          0 12628.4625          0          1 
           1        3       1100          0          0 12676.3341          0          1 
           2        1          0  3393.2241          0 13944.0613          0          1 
           2        2          0   732.1119          0 12340.4575          0          1 
           2        3          0   974.6630          0 12132.7666          0          1 
           3        1          0  4491.8722          0  2701.8266          0          1 
           3        2          0 12755.9657          0  2445.0556          0          1 
           3        3          0  4752.1604          0  2671.2305          0          1 
           4        1          0  1790.7874          0  3858.0189          0          1 
           4        2          0  3076.6366          0  3337.8784          0          1 
           4        3          0 11132.5806          0  3728.1412          0          1 
           5        1          0    69.5126          0     250000     250000          1 
           5        2          0   109.5081          0     120000     120000          1 
           5        3          0   124.2133          0     180000     180000          1
```

The problem is that when I read this with python with line.split('\t'), I end with just the whole line.

Comment: If this is a "copy-paste" of your actual data file, it appears to be formatted by spaces, not tabs. Have you tried simply `line.split()` ?

Comment: It looks like this example is formatted with fixed field widths: the least-significant digits are aligned rather than the most-significant digits.

Comment: Also, is the requirement that it be tab-delimited an external requirement? If you're in complete control of the software design, I would recommend using a machine-readable format (JSON, XML, CSV, etc) instead of a human-readable format, since the intention is to generate and parse them with Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comments, this appears to be just a space separated file with a variable number of spaces between cells. If that is the case, you can extract the cells from a particular row like this:

```
cells = line.split()
```

As for regenerating it, you'll need to pad the various columns to different widths. One way would be with code like this:

```
widths = [12,9,11,11,11,11,11,11]
paddedCells = [string.rjust(cell,widths[i]) for i,cell in enumerate(cells)]
line = ''.join(paddedCells)
```

Comment: actually I am using 
"%12d %8d %10.2f %10.2f %10.2f %10.2f %10.2f %10.1f\n"

Comment: @tcapelle In retrospect, that makes a lot more sense when you're working with the actual numbers and not just strings. Feel free to post your own solution and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

actually I am using

```
%12d %8d %10.2f %10.2f %10.2f %10.2f %10.2f %10.1f\n
```

The problem seems to be how the file are generated. I am pretty sure is not tab-delimited files.